# Cannot read property '_id' of undefined MONGODB / NODE.JS

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb

I need help. 
I'm make login with google signIn and I have this error

Cannot read property '_id' of undefined

And I'm can not solution.

In the terminal say my error is in line 97
[image]

this is my code:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you're getting the error during saving process (line 89 of your code).

As you can see in a callback you get two objects - `err` and `usuarioDB`. Add the error checking:

```
usuario.save((err, usuarioDB) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(500).json(message: err.message);
    }
    ...
})
```

This should give you a clue what's happening.